# Get "real" execution time of a SQL Server query?

Tags: sql-server

I have two stored stored procedures, where the second stored procedure is an improvement of the first one.

I'm trying to measure exactly how much is that improvement.

1/ Measuring `clock time` doesn't seem to be an option as I get different execution times. Even worse, sometimes (rarely, but it happens) the execution time of the second stored procedure is bigger than the execution time of the first procedure (I guess due to the server workload at that moment).

2/ `Include client statistics` also provides different results.

3/ `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS`, `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` are good, but the same story...

4/ `SET STATISTICS IO ON` could be an option, but how could I get an overall score as I have many tables involved in my stored procedures?

5/ `Include actual execution plan` could be an option also. I get an `estimated subtreecost` of 0.3253 for the first stored procedure, and 0.3079 for the second one. Can I say the second stored procedure is 6% faster (=0.3253/0.3079) ?

6/ Using "Reads" field from SQL Server Profiler? Even in this case I get different results when I execute those stored procedure many times.

**So how can I say the second stored procedure is x% faster than the first procedure, no matter the execution conditions (the workload of the server, the server where these stored procedures are executed, etc).**

If it is not possible, how can I prove the second stored procedure is more optimized.

Comment: i saw this question few minutes back also getting migrated to dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Similar to:- http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60651/how-to-measure-best-the-query-performance

Comment: Please do not migrate it, as there are dozen of similar questions here on stackoverflow, each question having a partial solution. It will be nice to have a single post where to have the complete answer, taking into account I have already aggregated the previous answers. Also, I don't see this necessarily related only to a DBA, it can be answered by a DBA or a developer.